# Grab div's select and use the option selected for input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div with the class of `.field_inputs` that is dynamic, meaning I can add as many as I want (on the click of "Add more"). Inside this div, there is a select dropdown and a text input.

I have a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rfPXx/

It looks like this:

```
<div class='field_inputs'>
   <select>
       <option value="saab">Saab</option>
       <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
       <option value="None">None</option>
   </select>
   <input type='text' name='test1'/>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is have it if you click on Saab in the dropdown, then the input (inside the same .field_inputs div as the select you clicked on) will be populated with text  (not necessarily the same text as the name of the select, though.) This is also just the default, the user should still be able to click on the input and change the text.

I have some jquery right now that looks like:

```
$(".field_inputs").each( function () {

    //Grab the select
    var thisSelect = this.find("select");

    //Grab the input
    var thisInput = this.find("input[type='text]");

    thisSelect.change(function(){

        switch( thisSelect.val() )
        {
        case "Saab":
          thisInput.val("State");
          break;
        case "Mercedes":
          thisInput.val("Country");
          break;
        }

    });
});
```

but it's giving me the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'find'
```

Comment: Change `this.find` to `$(this).find`. And switch/case is case-sensitive, like the rest of JavaScript, so nothing will ever match "Saab" or "Mercedes" since the actual values are lower case.

Comment: @the_ - you have capitalized `Saab` and `Mercedes`, but in the fiddle they are lowercase. Javascript is case-sensitive.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vp_arth/rfPXx/11/

Comment: PlantTheIdea, thanks didn't know that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the jQuery object `$(this)` rather than the HTML element `this`:

```
var thisSelect = $(this).find("select");
var thisInput = $(this).find("input[type='text]");
```

That said, there is no need for `.each()`:

```
$('.field_inputs').find('select').on('change',function(){
    var self = this,
        fieldInput = $(self).next().get(0);

    switch(self.value){
        case 'saab':
            fieldInput.value = 'State';
            break;
        case 'mercedes':
            fieldInput.value = 'Country';
            break;
    }
});
```

Or if the HTML doesn't always have the input as the next element in the DOM:

```
$('.field_inputs').find('select').on('change',function(){
    var self = this,
        fieldInput = $(self).parent().find('input[type="text"]').get(0);

    switch(self.value){
        case 'saab':
            fieldInput.value = 'State';
            break;
        case 'mercedes':
            fieldInput.value = 'Country';
            break;
    }
});
```

This will do the same thing, but much faster.

[Here is a working jsFiddle to show what I mean.](http://jsfiddle.net/rfPXx/7/)

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment above, change `this.find` to `$(this).find`. `.find()` is a jQuery method and you're trying to use it on a plain JavaScript reference. And fix the case of your case statement.

```
jQuery(function () {
    $(".field_inputs").each(function () {
        //Grab the select
        var thisSelect = $(this).find("select");
        //Grab the input
        var thisInput = $(this).find("input[type='text']");
        thisSelect.change(function () {
            switch (thisSelect.val()) {
                case "saab":
                    thisInput.val("State");
                    break;
                case "mercedes":
                    thisInput.val("Country");
                    break;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rfPXx/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

1. you're missing a quote in your selector input type: `var thisInput = this.find("input[type='text**'**]");`
2. the values in your switch statement are capitalized, while actual values are lower case, that's why your cases don't go through.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this to $(this). The reference of this is not being set to the current object.